# I use flask to change my visible state of a button. It seams like every style needs a diferente aproche?

Tags: python, html, flask, visibility

> This works fine, bud gives an css error message "at-rule or selector expected".

---

```
<button type="submit" id='saveCSV' name="SaveCSV" value='save'
            style="visibility: {{ btn_Guardar }} ;">Guardar</button>
```

---

> This works without any error's

---

```
<div id="floatingDiv" class="floating" style="display: '{{ floatingDivInitvalue }}' ;">
```

---

> This dos not work, no reaction at all.?

---

```
<button type="submit" id='saveCSV' name="SaveCSV" value='save'
            style="visibility: '{{ btn_Guardar }}' ;">Guardar</button>
```

---

> > I want tu use visibility how do I do It  ?
>
> Just made a new test and this has definitely something to do with de quotation marks. I can see in the console window that `"visibility: '{{ btn_Guardar }}'` leave the quitación marks "on" `style="visibility:'hidden';"` and that's why it is not working. The question still remains what to do?

Comment: Why do prefer controlling the visibility with flask instead of Javascript? Beside, why do you prefere css visibility over display?

Comment: The visibility "reserve" the space for the button, in this case it's needed. I use flask to post change DataFrames on the web page and therefore I let flask control the states of the buttons.